# inno setup regsvr32 fails

Tags: dll, com, inno-setup, regsvr32

i have a DLL with COM interface and like to install it with Inno Setup 5.5
but Inno Setup fails with regsvr32 with code 0x5. Generally this should point
to a privileges issue.

Using manually regsvr32 in an admin console, the DLL/COM gets registered without eorrs and i can see the typelibrary with OleView.

It just fails with Inno Setup.

```
  source\my.dll"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Check: IsWin64; Flags: ignoreversion  regserver 64bit; 

source\my.dll"; DestDir: "{syswow64}";  Check: IsWin64; Flags: ignoreversion  regserver  32bit
```

Some other parameter should make sure to start install with admin privileges:

```
PrivilegesRequired=admin
ArchitecturesAllowed=x86 x64
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
```

Anyone has an idea what's wrong ?
Thank you

Comment: Peculiar. You're sure the innosetup installer actually runs in elevated right mode?